# AmCharts v4. How to set default non-active state for single slice in Pie Charts? (Like after click on legend)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I use the new version of AmCharts - v4.

How can I set a disabled state for some slice when the chart is loading?
Like after click on the legend label - Pie chart redraws and doesn't contain this slice.